# Enable global menu on Eclipse running on minimal Ubuntu Core

Tags: unity, 16.04, eclipse

Global menus work fine out of the box in a minimal Ubuntu installation for `gtk2` apps, and `gtk3` apps run just as fine if `libdbusmenu-gtk3-4` is installed.

But for Eclipse, I've installed `jayatana`, `libdbusmenu-gtk3-4`, `libdbusmenu-gtk4`, `gnome-menus`, but nothing seems to work. What exactly is missing here? I can't find any more DBus or global menu packages that are installed on standard Desktop to try.

**PS** For the record, Eclipse runs fine with global menu on a normal Ubuntu Desktop installation.

Comment: Did you have a look at these? http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/gnome/indicator-appmenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install the required libraries

   ```
   sudo apt install unity-gtk3-module
   ```
2. Set GTK module variable to use Unity module, add the line below:

   ```
   $ nano ~/.profile 

   export GTK_MODULES=$GTK_MODULES:unity-gtk-module
   ```